# Copy items from CheckedListBox to ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, checkedlistbox

I'm trying to copy the CheckedItems from a `CheckedListBox` to a `Listbox`, but I am not getting it right.

I have tried

```
Listbox.Items.Add(checkedlistbox.CheckedItems);
```

but that only gives me a (collection)

Does anyone have a great line of code to share? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach(var Item in checkedlistbox.CheckedItems)
    Listbox.Items.Add(Item);
```

Edit: replaced string with var so it works with non-string types too.

Comment: replace _string_ with _var_ if the items aren't strings

Comment: @Tigran Obviously it would. He hasn't mentioned the type of item he has in his Checked Listbox and since only strings can be added in Listbox, I infer that he using string type items in his Checked Listbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string item = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
else
    listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
```

You should write it in the ItemCheck event.
With this code you can show the checked items in the other listBox.